# Expand 3 ranked image to a 4 ranked one (for keras ImageDataGenerator().fit )

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have an image with the shape (10, 256, 256) and I must add one dimension at the beginning that represents the number of channels the image has (in my case 3), how should I do that?

ValueError: Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. Got array with shape: (10, 256, 256)

I also tried this:

```
X_train = numpy.array(X_train)
X_train = numpy.reshape(X_train, (1, len(X_train), targ_size[0], targ_size[1]))

datagen_train.fit(X_train)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods to increase the dimension of an array:

```
X_new1 = X_train[np.newaxis]
X_new2 = X_train[None]
X_new3 = X_train.reshape((1,)+X_train.shape)
X_new4 = np.expand_dims(X_train,0)
```

`X_new1, X_new2, X_new3`and `X_new4` are all equivalent

Furthermore `X_new1`and `X_new2` are even "more equivalent", as the use the same idea. i.e. `np.newaxis` is equivalent to `None`.

Same holds for method 3 and 4, method 4 internally calls method 3